# find the solution of $2x\sin{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dx+3y\cos{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dx-3x\cos{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A solution of the equation
$$2x\sin{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dx+3y\cos{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dx-3x\cos{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dy=0$$

I know the answer $c\sin(3y/x)$
but I don't know the solution

Comment: Your differential equationis not correct a $dx$ is missing or at least  parenthessa are missing.

Comment: Typical homogeneous example.

Comment: @hih: You have removed your question details. Re-edit the details to clarify question you are asking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite O.D.E: $2x\sin{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dx+3y\cos{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dx-3x\cos{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dy=0$ as follows
$$\left(2\sin{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}+3\frac yx\cos{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}\right)-3\cos{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
Substitute $y=vx\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$
$$\left(2\sin v+3v\cos v\right)-3\cos v\left(v+x\frac{dv}{dx}\right)=0$$
$$\cot v\ dv=-\frac{2}{3}\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$3\int \cot v\ dv=-2\int \frac{dx}{x}+C$$
$$3\ln\sin v=-2\ln x+\ln c $$
$$\ln\sin^3 v=\ln\left(\frac{c}{x^2}\right)$$
$$\sin^3 v=\frac{c}{x^2}$$
$$\sin^3 \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\frac{c}{x^2}$$
$$x^2\sin^3 \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=c$$

Comment: I don't know why cotv dv=−2/3(dx/x) is happening.. And I'm really sorry, but can you solve it until the end?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$2x\sin{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dx+3y\cos{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dx-3x\cos{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}dy=0$$
Substitute $y=tx$ and solve.